# Can't start Docker Desktop due to Windows group policy

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I've updated Docker Desktop from 4.6.1 to 4.11.1, but after that I can't start Docker Desktop nor docker service. I looked in the logs and found this message:

```
[2022-08-12T19:27:53.379639400Z][com.docker.backend.exe][F] fork/exec C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
```

I see the error is provoked by a policy that the company where I work at has on every computer and it's something I can't change, so my question is:

Is there any way to configure Docker to start using CMD instead of Powershell? Or do I have to reinstall previous version and avoid updating?

Comment: Normally administrators will roll out special (more relaxed) rules on developer machines. So tell them, that you need powershell for your work and they will allow it.